# Clearing datagridview starting from the chosen row

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to clear the datagridview starting from the row which user chose. I am trying a few ways to implement it, but they all generate some errors, now I have something like this:

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if(row.Index >= odelementu - 1)
      dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(row.Index);
}
```

User need to choose from which row we should clear the datagridview and then click the button

```
odelementu //this variable represents the starting row
```

I don't know why the loop misses some rows. I would be grateful for any advices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you modify the `DataGridViewRowCollection` in the `foreach` loop and make the `index` gotten becomes `inexact`. Try this instead:

```
while(dataGridView1.Rows.Count>=odelementu) {
  dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(odelementu-1);
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly, tell if the source of problem is that when we remove row the other one gets different indexes ?

Comment: @MyWay yes, it's something like that.

Comment: @MyWay if you want to use `for-loop`, you have to loop from the last row to the first.

Comment: @MyWay if it works, you should mark the answer as accepted to make it `distinct` and help others also take benefit :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public void RemoveRows()
{
  var selectedrows = datagridview.SelectedRows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>();
  if (selectedrows.Count() == 0)
      return;
  var fromIndex = selectedrows.Last().Index;
  datagridview.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
      .Where(p=>p.Index > fromIndex)
      .ToList()
      .ForEach(p=>datagridview.Rows.Remove(p));

}
```